# Multiple viewports on one Pyglet window?

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I need to make mutiple viewports of cube in python Pyglet, but i always just have one.

Look at def on_resize():

```
WINDOW = 1000 
INCREMENT = 5
transparant = False

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    xRotation = yRotation = zRotation = 30
    zoom = 1
    far = 100
    dist = 35
    x = y = z = 0

    def __init__(self, width, height, title = '') :
        super(Window, self).__init__( 1300,1000, title)
        pgl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
        pgl.glEnable(pgl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)



    def on_draw(self) :

        self.clear()
```

cube drawing

```
        pgl.glPopMatrix()

    def on_resize(self, width, height) :
        pgl.glClear(pgl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | pgl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        pgl.glViewport(0, 0, 650, 500)
        pgl.glLoadIdentity()
        pgl.glMatrixMode(ogl.GL_PROJECTION)
        pgl.glOrtho(-width / 8, width / 8, -height / 8, height / 8, 0, 500)
        pgl.glFlush()

        pgl.glViewport(500, 0, 650, 500)
        pgl.glLoadIdentity()
        pgl.glMatrixMode(ogl.GL_PROJECTION)
        Ratio = width/height
        # pgl.gluPerspective(self.dist, Ratio, 1, 1000)
        pgl.glOrtho(-width/8, width/8, -height/8, height/8, 0, 500)
        pgl.glFlush()
        pgl.glMatrixMode(ogl.GL_MODELVIEW)
        pgl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -100)

Window(WINDOW, WINDOW, 'Cube')
pyglet.app.run()
```

Can you help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the viewport and matrices will modify OpenGL state. You have to draw something right after that. Setting a new viewport will just override the previous setting. Something like:

```
pgl.glClear(pgl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | pgl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

pgl.glViewport(0, 0, 650, 500)    
pgl.glMatrixMode(ogl.GL_PROJECTION)
pgl.glLoadIdentity()
pgl.glOrtho(-width / 8, width / 8, -height / 8, height / 8, 0, 500)
pgl.glMatrixMode(ogl.GL_MODELVIEW)
# set modelview matrix
# draw cube

pgl.glViewport(500, 0, 650, 500)
pgl.glMatrixMode(ogl.GL_PROJECTION)
pgl.glLoadIdentity()
# this is actually the same as before, so you can just leave it
pgl.glOrtho(-width/8, width/8, -height/8, height/8, 0, 500)
pgl.glMatrixMode(ogl.GL_MODELVIEW)
pgl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -100)
# set modelview matrix
# draw cube
```

Comment: how can i call on_draw func? if i create seperated function to draw cube, cube doesn't move, rotate or zoom (I need to do this things), it only works if it is inside on_draw
https://pastebin.com/gziTksSa
full code, so u can understand me correctly

Comment: Sure, all drawing should happen in `on_draw`. The code here should go exactly there.

Comment: Thank you, that works, and mb you know how to make different orthogonal projections? I made from the front and I need one more from side

Comment: Rotate the cube using the modelview matrix accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general tip/hint/rule for OpenGL beginners, struggling with these kinds of problems:

*While you're learning, **make no OpenGL calls outside the drawing function**!* Setting up matrices, the viewport and so and *always* goes into the drawing function.